# How can I setup a django site in a vps

Tags: django, apache, vps

I am trying to setup a django site in a VPS, hosted in hostgator. I have done it on a apache server once in a different system. But the httpd.conf file did not have nameserver and multiple enteries for WHM and Cpanel on that system. I followed the documentation and was successful for it. But for the VPS I am a bit confused. The tech guys in hostgator are not helping.

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't Say that it will work perfectly with apache. I also first tried with apache configurations but end up with nginx from this tutorial:

**https://www.shellvoide.com/hacks/installing-django-application-with-nginx-mysql-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-vps/**